# What does Gal(Q_p/Q) mean?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, galois-theory, galois-groups, absolute-galois-group

What does
$\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_{p}/\mathbb{Q})$ mean? ($p$ is a prime number.)

If it is defined as $\mathrm{Aut}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_{p}/\mathbb{Q})$, then does it have any property like usual galois groups?

For example, is the following statement true? :

Let $\alpha \in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}_{p}$, and assume that for any $\sigma \in \mathrm{Aut} (\overline{ \mathbb{Q} } _{p} / \mathbb{Q})$, $\sigma (\alpha) = \alpha$. Then, $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}$.

If this is true, then how can I prove it?

Please give me any advice.

## Thanks!

Comment: Please read http://mathoverflow.net/faq#whatnot . $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p} / \mathbb{Q}_p$ is an infinite Galois extension.

Comment: (but over $\mathbb{Q}$ it's not Galois)

Comment: @Hiro: One can use the axiom of choice to construct an isomorphism of abstract fields (i.e. ignoring the topology) $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p} \cong \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$.

Comment: @Daniel: No, one cannot. $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ is countable, $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ is not.

Comment: @Robert: Yes of course I was being completely stupid, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is true. A way to prove this is to use the existence of [transcendence basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendence_degree) for field extensions, and the fact that $\overline{\mathbf{Q}_p}$ is algebraically closed.

First, assume $\alpha$ is transcendental. Then there exists a transcendence basis $S$ of $\overline{\mathbf{Q}_p}/\mathbf{Q}$ containing $\alpha$. By permuting the elements of $S$, there exists an automorphism $\sigma$ of $\mathbf{Q}(S)$ such that $\sigma(\alpha) \neq \alpha$. Since $\overline{\mathbf{Q}_p}$ is an algebraic closure of $\mathbf{Q}(S)$, you can extend $\sigma$ to an automorphism of $\overline{\mathbf{Q}_p}$, which gives a contradiction.

Finally, if $\alpha \in \overline{\mathbf{Q}}$ but $\alpha \not\in \mathbf{Q}$, then you can take the Galois closure $L$ of $\mathbf{Q}(\alpha)$ and find an automorphism $\sigma$ of $L$ such that $\sigma(\alpha) \neq \alpha$. Then, repeating the above argument, you can extend $\sigma$ to $\overline{\mathbf{Q}_p}$, which gives a contradiction.

Note that the argument works replacing $\overline{\mathbf{Q}_p}$ by any algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$.

Comment: Oh, I did not think that it is such a general fact!
And your proof is clear and interesting!
Thank you so much!